# How to link external Xaml page to a Grid in Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to link an external .xaml file into a grid in my Universal Windows Platform App.

This is the folder structure:

[image]

I want to link ListView.xaml into a grid which is declared inside MainPage.xaml

Codes for both file :

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="TodoGrocery.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TodoGrocery"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="gridView" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Background="#3A5194">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
            <SymbolIcon  Symbol="Back" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Height="40"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="title" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="Todo Grocery"></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="moreButton" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="More" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Height="40"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>



    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Page><!-- Link ListView.xaml Here--></Page>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

ListView.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="TodoGrocery.ListView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TodoGrocery"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="listHeader" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="#d0d0d0" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,9,0,9"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Column="1">
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Sort"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Quantity" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,0"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ListPanel" Grid.Row="1"></Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ButtonPanel" Grid.Row="2" Background="#3A5194">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="deleteAllButton" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent">
            <!--<SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete" Foreground="White"/>-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0">Delete All</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="addButton" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent">
            <!--<SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete" Foreground="White"/>-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" Width="100">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add" Foreground="white"/>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="15,5,0,0">Add</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

So this is what I'm planning to do with my app :

I will be having different external pages like ListView.xaml and whenever user clicks a link or a tab, the part where the page is linked should be changed with the page that has been asked for.

Thanks. Any other ideas are also appreciated.

Comment: For UWP, read [Navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187344.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Use `UserControl` or `TemplatedControl` instead `Page`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include a Page inside of another, use the [`Frame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame) object:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"></Frame>
</Grid>
```

Then, to load a page inside of the Frame, just call the `Navigate` method:

```
this.MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(TodoGrocery.ListView));
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kory said, you can know how to do what you want in UWP by reading [Navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187344.aspx) chapter in How-to guides for Windows 10 apps.

The key point here is using [`Frame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.aspx) and [`Frame.Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate.aspx) methods. The frame hosts the pages and keeps the navigation history.

> You create as many different page types as needed to present the content in your app, and then navigate to those pages by calling the Navigate method and passing in the type of the page to navigate to. You can also pass in a parameter object to initialize the page to a particular state.

So you can change your MainPage.xaml like following to link ListView.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="TodoGrocery.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:TodoGrocery"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="gridView" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Background="#3A5194">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                <SymbolIcon  Symbol="Back" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Height="40"/>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="title" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="Todo Grocery"></TextBlock>
            <Button x:Name="moreButton" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="More" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Height="40"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Frame x:Name="MyFrame">
                <local:ListView />
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Or just add a `Frame` in Grid:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Frame x:Name="MyFrame" />
</Grid>
```

And in code-behind, using

```
MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(TodoGrocery.ListView));
```